# How to customize the comments form?

Tags: 8, forms, comments, theming

For example, How can I add some classes or hide labels and instead of it add placeholder with using of `ThemeName_preprocess_comment` to 'subject' and 'name' comments form elements?

I have tried to use`drupal_set_message(kint($variables));` in `ThemeName_preprocess_comment` section, but it cause the empty screen erroe in my site.

So how can I add some classes to default (or my own created) comments elements so I can target them for adding CSS style.

How can I target default comments form element in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do it:

1) create new file: testmodule.info.yml.

```
name: testmodule
description: Testmodule
type: module
core: 8.x
```

2) create new file: testmodule.module

```
<?php


function testmodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id=='comment_comment_form') {

    //add class subject
    $form['subject']['widget']['0']['value']['#attributes']['class'][]='newclass_subject';

    //add placeholder subject
    $form['subject']['widget']['0']['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder Subject');


    //add class body
    $form['comment_body']['widget']['0']['#attributes']['class'][]='newclass_body';

    //add placeholder body
    $form['comment_body']['widget']['0']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder Body');

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use Drupal7, you should not use

```
drupal_set_message(kint($variables));
```

but

```
kint($variables)
```

or

```
dpm($variables)
```

An example that you can see, enter in the following link:
 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7.x

```
function bartik_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {

  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'myclass';
  dpm($variables);

}
```

You can also create a file "comment-wrapper.tpl.php" and add the classes you want and placeholder.

Example:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Bartik's theme implementation to provide an HTML container for comments.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $content: The array of content-related elements for the node. Use
 *   render($content) to print them all, or
 *   print a subset such as render($content['comment_form']).
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. The default value has the following:
 *   - comment-wrapper: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
 * - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
 *   appears in the template.
 * - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
 *   the template.
 *
 * The following variables are provided for contextual information.
 * - $node: Node object the comments are attached to.
 * The constants below the variables show the possible values and should be
 * used for comparison.
 * - $display_mode
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_FLAT
 *   - COMMENT_MODE_THREADED
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_comment_wrapper()
 */
?>
<?php 
    //add placeholder
    $content['comment_form']['subject']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Title');
    $content['comment_form']['comment_body']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Comment Body');
  ?>
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'): ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h2 class="title"><?php print t('Comments'); ?></h2>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

  <?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
    <h2 class="title comment-form "><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help and reply, I appreciate you greatly, But I use Drupal 8. thanks anyway.